# How to restart/release rfcomm for bluetooth communication?

Tags: bluetooth, peripherals, bluez, process

I am trying to connect raspberry pi to my galaxy note to use it for serial communication. I have somewhat succeeded at that.

First I paired it and trusted through `bluetoothctl`. Then I run `sudo rfcomm watch hci0` and opened with `cat /dev/rfcomm`. I was able to connect to raspberry pi using [bluetooth terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.sash0k.bluetooth_terminal&hl=en) (only this app, every other one failed) and strings sent from galaxy would be shown in the `cat` window.

I have somehow messed up later and now running `sudo rfcomm watch hci0` gives me `Can't bind RFCOMM socket: Address already in use`. I can't release it with `sudo rfcomm release hci0` or `sudo rfcomm release 0` as it then gives me `Can't release device: No such device`. Likewise `cat /dev/rfcomm0` too now gives me `No such file or directory`.

I killed the process listed with `sudo lsof | grep /dev/rfcomm0`, this had no effect on my ability to use RFCOMM. Reloading with `systemctl daemon-reload` and restarting with `service bluetooth restart` too has had no effect.

I can still scan for other bluetooth devices, and I can connect to raspberry pi with bluetooth terminal, but it seems rfcomm is gone. I am aware that rebooting can solve this, though I would like to do that programatically if possible without having to resort to power-cycling.

I have seen similar issue pop up on this stack, but have not found an answer that would solve this issue.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

rfcomm is one of the tools that has been [deprecated](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) by the BlueZ team as working at that low level can lead to unpleasant things happening on the system because those tools by passed the the bluetooth daemon that is running.
There are higher levels of API available to use that go through tbe Bluetooth daemon.

A couple of Python examples of how to create an rfcomm (Serial Port Profile) server are:

http://blog.kevindoran.co/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3/

https://bluedot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btcommapi.html#bluetoothserver